# Error on page load in IE8 (triggers compatability view)

Tags: view, ie8-compatibility-mode, compatibility

***Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 136
Char: 8
Code: 0***

**This is the section where it occurs** - (6th-last line: '},')

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.init({
                            name : "Default Ajax Search that works with Twentyten 2011-03-14 23:09:31",
                            name_md5 : "f02b704d9a6e3111c721adb5de87e883",
                            chars_before_search : 0,
                            time_before_search : 200,
                            cursor_key_navigation : 1,
                            cursor_key_navigation_loops : 1,
                            results_to_display : 10,
                            selector_search_form : "#searchform",
                            selector_search_input : "#s",
                            selector_search_results : ".hentry",
                            selector_search_results_content : ".threewp_ajax_search_results_content ul",
                            display_format_header : "<div class=\"threewp_ajax_search_results_content\">\
<ul>",
                            display_format_item : "<li class=\"%item_class%\">%item%</li>",
                            display_format_footer : "</ul>\
</div>",
                            callbacks : {
                                "after_init" : function(form_object, callback){
    $("input", form_object).attr("autocomplete", "off");
    callback();
},
                                "after_fetch" : function(form_object, callback){
    callback();
},
                                "before_hide" : function(form_object, callback){
    $(".threewp_ajax_search_container", form_object).fadeTo(250, 0.0, callback);
}
,
                                "before_show" : function(form_object, callback){
    $(".threewp_ajax_search_container", form_object).fadeTo(250, 1.0, callback);
}
,
                            },
                            search_url : "http://domain.com/?s="
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `before_show` line has a trailing comma, after the `}`:

```
"before_show" : function(form_object, callback){
    $(".threewp_ajax_search_container", form_object).fadeTo(250, 1.0, callback);
}
,
```

Trailing commas aren't strictly legal in JS, and IE throws an error on them. Remove the trailing comma and it should work.

Comment: that did the trick to get the error! thank you.however, i also had to specify IE8 rendering vs IE7/compatibility mode in the <head> using the following: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />. everything renders correctly.